# Parameter list VS returned function

Tags: scala, function, parameters

I've been experimenting with Scala. I am trying to understand implicits and came across this situation.

1. Is behaviour of parameter `b` same for both functions?
2. Are paramareters list just syntax sugar over returning function?

My experiments show, they behave the same.

Thanks

```
implicit val v = 2

// 1.
def testB(a: Int)(b: Int)(implicit i: Int): Int = {
  println(a + b + i)
  11
}
println(testB(7)(8))
println(testB(7) {
  8
})

// 2.
def testC(a: Int): (Int) => Int = {
  def innerTest2C(b: Int)(implicit i: Int) = {
    println(a + b + i)
    11
  }
  innerTest2C
}

println(testC(7)(8))
println(testC(7) {
  8
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that whenever a function takes exactly one parameter, you can replace the normal brackets `()` with curly brackets `{}`. Curly brackets define a block and allow you to place several statements inside it. The block will evaluate to the value of the expression in the last line like in all blocks.

In 2., the function testC returns another function from `Int` to `Int`, so you cann call the result of `testC(7)` again with one parameter: `testC(7)(x)`. If you just consider the println statements, there is nothing different here.

What you need to understand is that

```
def testB(a: Int)(b: Int)
```

is different from

```
def testB(a: Int, b: Int)
```

insofar that the former represents two functions like in your second case. You can call testB(x) and will obtain another function from `Int` to `Int`. Applying only part of the paramters of a function in order to obtain another function is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).